# Can indistinguishable particle wavefunctions be written as a product of total observable eigenstates?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quarks, pauli-exclusion-principle, baryons, color-charge

Consider the wavefunction of say two electrons in an external potential, associated with two possible states $\phi_a$ and $\phi_b$. Furthermore, each electron can have two spin states $\chi_1$ and $\chi_2$. A convenient basis for the anti-symmetric Hilbert space of the two electrons is (omitting the normalizations)
\begin{equation}
(\phi_a\phi_b + \phi_b\phi_a)(\chi_1\chi_2 - \chi_2\chi_1),\quad (\phi_a\phi_a)(\chi_1\chi_2 - \chi_2\chi_1),\quad (\phi_b\phi_b)(\chi_1\chi_2 - \chi_2\chi_1)\\
(\phi_a\phi_b - \phi_b\phi_a)(\chi_1\chi_2 + \chi_2\chi_1),\quad (\phi_a\phi_b - \phi_b\phi_a)(\chi_1\chi_1),\quad (\phi_a\phi_b - \phi_b\phi_a)(\chi_2\chi_2).
\end{equation}
This is convenient since the total wavefunction factors out in a spatial- and spin-wavefunction with even or odd exchange symmetry and, moreover, the spin part are just the different eigenstates of the total spin of the system. The fact that the above system is indeed a basis of the anti-symmetric Hilbert space is  a speciality of a two particle system with two "available" quantum numbers (here the "spatial quantum number" ($a$ and $b$) and the spin).

Ever so often, however, one comes across a situation where people write down the total wavefunction of a larger system. E.g. of the [wavefunction of a baryon](https://www8.physics.utoronto.ca/%7Ekrieger/Phy489_Lecture10_2013.pdf). The document states that the total wavefunction is given as a product of properly symmetrized wavefunctions of the different quantum numbers, i.e.
\begin{equation}
\Psi_{total} = \psi(\text{space})\psi(\text{spin})\psi(\text{colour})\psi(\text{flavour}).
\end{equation}

Why does this make sense? One would obviously miss a potentially large part of the accessible Hilbert space. Also the above wavefunction is used as evidence for the colour quantum number in the first place, as otherwise certain (observed) states would violate the exchange-symmetry condition (precisely when the other products together yield a symmetric wavefunction). This argument seems to be wrong since more states than the ones captured by the above "basis" are present.

Comment: Are you sure the people who say this aren't just being a bit sloppy with their language and what they mean is that a *basis* for the wavefunctions is given by $\Psi_\text{total}$ of that form? What part of the Hilbert space exactly do you think one "obviously" misses here?

Comment: Well but the $\Psi_{total}$ don't neccesarily constitute a basis of the antisymmetric Hilbert space no?

Comment: What state do you think is not expressible as a sum of states of that form? Please write it down explicitly.

Comment: Consider my example above for 3 particles. You can still find antisymmetric states (eg put two particles with opposite spin in the a orbital and then the remaining one in the b orbital). But it's not possible to factor out the wavefunction in a spatial and a spin function

Comment: It is not obvious to me that the state you described cannot be written as the *sum* of basic tensors like $\Psi_\text{total}$, though. Again, please write it down explicitly - I find that the somewhat vague description in words doesn't make for good understanding what your problem is here.

Comment: Okay, but that's a different statement. Since all $\Psi_{total}$ of the above form (without the symmetry constraint tho) constitute a basis of the entire Hilbert space, they can obviously also be used to create a basis of the antisymmetric Hilbert space. 
But there is no single "product state" (space*spin) that could describe an antisymmetric state.

Comment: So, there are antisymmetric states for the three particle system, but still you cannot write them in the $\Psi_{total}$ form. Does this mean we need to introduce another quantum number? Probably not...

Answer (score 0):

Let us formulate your question a bit more abstractly:

You are starting from a one-particle space of the form $H = H_1\otimes\dots \otimes H_k$, where the $H_i$ are spaces like the "position space", "spin space", "flavour space", etc.

You are then forming the $n$-particle space $H^{\otimes n} = (H_1\otimes \dots H_n)^{\otimes n} = H^{\otimes n}_1 \otimes\dots\otimes H^{\otimes n}_k $ and you are applying either the symmetrization operator $\mathrm{Sym}$ or the anti-symmetrization operator $\Lambda$ to it.

You are asking why a basis for e.g. $\mathrm{Sym}^n(H)$ is given by tensors of the form $\psi = \psi_1 \otimes \dots\otimes \psi_k$ where each of the $\psi_i$ is in $\mathrm{Sym}^n(H_i)$ or $\Lambda^n(H_i)$ such that the total tensor has the correct symmetry properties.

The answer is: It's not, this is indeed just one piece of the total Hilbert space. According to [this MO answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1776494/143136) and the book by Fulton/Harris on representation theory of the symmetric group one can use the [Littlewood-Richardson rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Littlewood%E2%80%93Richardson_rule) for [Schur polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_polynomial) to argue that
$$ \mathrm{Sym}^n(V\otimes W) = \bigoplus_{\alpha|n} S^\alpha(V)\otimes S^\alpha(W),$$
where $S^\alpha$ is a [Schur factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_functor) corresponding to a Young diagram $\alpha$ with $n$ boxes and a similar decomposition for the anti-symmetric product. The spaces $\mathrm{Sym}^n(V)\otimes \mathrm{Sym}^n(W)$ and $\Lambda^n(V)\otimes \Lambda^n(W)$ are just summands in this decomposition, but for $n> 2$ there are indeed more.

Comment: So you say you proved that if your $\psi$ is symmetric and is a product of all the $\psi_i$, it follows that each of the $\psi_i$ is itself (anti-)symmetric. But how does this matter? It's not clear that such a $\psi$ exists in the first place, nor that you find enough to build a basis, right?

Comment: To be more concrete, consider the following. So for my 3-fermion example you would have to find a $\psi$ that's given as $\psi = \phi(x_1, x_2)\chi(s_1, s_2)$. Since $\psi$ is antisymmetric, one of the factors has to be antisymmetric the other one symmetric. However, it is *not* possible to find an antisymmetric wavefunction in a space with dimension smaller than the particle number. Therefore, no such $\psi$ exists

Comment: @user2224350 Okay, last try: I think you're right but I think it would really have helped if you had been a bit more explicit about the states you think are not covered here. I've found several references that deal with decomposing symmetric powers of tensor products and edited the answer again.

Comment: What do you think does this imply for the article I referenced? How can one save the arguement being made for the existence of the colour quantum number? The article argues that you need colour to be able to write down a totally antisymmetric wavefunction as a product of (anti-)symmetric wavefunctions $\psi_i$. Since, based on our discussion, a legitimate antisymmetric state doesn't have to look like this the arguement seems to be wrong. However, maybe demanding that the total state $\psi$ is an eigenstate to all the total observables (total spin, total angular momentum, ...) saves the day?

Comment: @user2224350 What you referenced is a slide show, not an article. How we conclude colour exists is a different question entirely but suffice it to say that there are plenty of other stronger arguments for QCD than some symmetry arguments.

Comment: Yes I know, also in the link they talk about other evidence. I'm not doubting the existence of colour, I'm just trying to make sense of the wavefunction argument

Answer (score -2):

Basis does not mean each unit vector is a physically valid state. For instance look at the states you wrote:

\begin{equation}
(\phi_a\phi_b + \phi_b\phi_a)(\chi_1\chi_2 - \chi_2\chi_1),\quad (\phi_a\phi_a)(\chi_1\chi_2 - \chi_2\chi_1),\quad (\phi_b\phi_b)(\chi_1\chi_2 - \chi_2\chi_1)\\
(\phi_a\phi_b - \phi_b\phi_a)(\chi_1\chi_2 + \chi_2\chi_1),\quad (\phi_a\phi_b - \phi_b\phi_a)(\chi_1\chi_1),\quad (\phi_a\phi_b - \phi_b\phi_a)(\chi_2\chi_2).
\end{equation}

These can all be decomposed and written into the basis

\begin{equation}
\rvert \phi_i \rangle \rvert \phi_j \rangle\rvert \chi_m \rangle\rvert \chi_n \rangle
\end{equation}

for all valid $i,j,m,n$, e.g.
\begin{equation}
(\phi_a\phi_b + \phi_b\phi_a)(\chi_1\chi_2 - \chi_2\chi_1) = \rvert \phi_a \rangle \rvert \phi_b \rangle\rvert \chi_1 \rangle\rvert \chi_2 \rangle + \rvert \phi_b \rangle \rvert \phi_a \rangle\rvert \chi_1 \rangle\rvert \chi_2 \rangle - \rvert \phi_a \rangle \rvert \phi_b \rangle\rvert \chi_2 \rangle\rvert \chi_1 \rangle - \rvert \phi_b \rangle \rvert \phi_a \rangle\rvert \chi_2 \rangle\rvert \chi_1 \rangle.
\end{equation}

Why is this the case? Because the basis has a state that represents all possible measurement outcomes on the system.

Comment: Your basis is not a basis of the antisymmetric Hilbert space.. Also, I don't see your point..

Comment: Yes it is, elements of the antisymmetric Hilbert space are points within the space spanned by the basis. I'm saying your confusion is that you are thinking that basis is the same thing as "all and only physical states". It is not

Comment: Ok so technically the states you gave are not a basis of the antisym. Hilbertspace (the basis vectors need to be in the space they're supposed to span). Anyways, which states fo you consider now unphysical? The states I wrote down or you basis states?

Comment: My states, e.g. $\rvert \phi_a \rangle \rvert \phi_b \rangle\rvert \chi_1 \rangle\rvert \chi_2 \rangle$ is not a physical state (due to symmetry), but every state that is valid is a linear combination of such states. To write down all possible states of the system, you can use basis vectors of the form $\rvert \phi_i \rangle \rvert \phi_j \rangle\rvert \chi_m \rangle\rvert \chi_n \rangle$ . Your states are physical, I was just showing that they can be written as linear combinations of the unphysical states. That's what the slides mean by basis, whether that is normal parlance in math, IDK.

Comment: For instance, a mass on a spring can never be further from the origin than the length of the spring, but you might still say the real number line is a valid configuration space for the system. You can still do analysis of the harmonic oscillator over $\mathbb{R}$ even though not all elements are physical.

Comment: To the people downvoting me. This is the answer, don't get upset with me that physcists aren't careful with their language.